# Close Audit failed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed the audit below https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21525131

[image: Half of a closed, deleted question shows the code. The score was at -7.]
[image: 2nd half of the question asks why the program outputs specific values. The close notice on the question is Too Broad.]

Question seems OK to me. I marked it as "Keep Open".

One thing that I noticed is that the post was marked closed on Nov 3rd and then it was edited on Nov 10th. I cannot see the history as it is a deleted post, but maybe the extra information was added on Nov 10th to make this post OK.

Comment: The edit only modified the title, the body was not changed. I can only guess why the question was closed (and I don't think it was that bad).

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it's okay? Seems a bit like homework to me, _why does this code do that_ often are homework questions, especially when the code is purely hypothetical and doesn't really do anything. I probably would've closed this if I encountered it. It's also triple-barreled, asking about 3 different returns.

Comment: The OP is trying to get an answer on copy constructor in three separate initialization scenarios. This can help to get a fuller understanding on a topic. The three questions are very related. Even though the question may be homework, it seems to be of OK quality.

Comment: Rejecting the flag when the question is deleted is indeed a good way to fail an audit.  Just keep in mind that the goal here is to handle flags, not to state your own preferences about C++ questions.  The question is fine, but the [c++] community has, erm, high standards for what they wish to answer.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not sure I understand you. The question asks why a specific piece of code behaves as it does. How is that a bad question? If the question is fine, then why is it closed? And how is the reviewer here supposed to know that some other people closed a fine question?

Comment: I'm merely relaying [c++] community attitudes, I have no real taste for trying to explain them.  It is not my taste.  Two of the close voters have in fact demanded more votes so they can close more of these questions, might be a good idea to look at their meta requests.  The "supposed to know" is not that difficult, the question was deleted a week ago.  Not seeing that is all that an audit really checks for.

Comment: One more point I would like to add here is that the post was edited after it was closed. In this case, there was no major change. But what if substantial information was added by the OP later on. What is the expected behaviour then?

Comment: What I especially don't get is how that question could be considered as too broad (and also why this meta question is getting so many downvotes)

Comment: @DidierL The meta question could be getting downvotes because it is yet another "I failed this audit! Woe is me!", instead of the more palatable, "I saw this question was deleted after failing an audit. Can we discuss why the question was deleted?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm agreeing with the "too broad" reason since there are distinct questions being asked here.

> For the first "cout", it outputs 124 because o1 has been incremented
>   by 1.
>
> For the second "cout", why does it output 123? In my understanding,
>   the data pointer now points to the value of 124. Can anyone go through
>   this "cout" step by step?
>
> For the third "cout", I'm not sure if I understand this right. o3 was
>   created by calling the second constructor which is the copying
>   constructor so it is the same as "o3(123)". And it outputs 123.

The smoking gun here is the first question there; asking us to go through this code step by step makes this an easier target for broadness.

I personally don't think the question is *poor*, but the OP could've edited it to make it more of a coherent, distinct question rather than having two distinct questions being posed.